# Calculating Lending Rate Using Algofi Python SDK

Tags: algorand

I am attempting to calculate the lending interest rate of [Algofi](https://info.algofi.org/lend-info/) pools. This is [calculated](https://docs.algofi.org/algofi-lending/interest-rate-model) like:
`Supply Interest Rate = Borrow Utilization * Borrow Interest Rate * (1 - Reserve Factor)`

I have been using the Algo lending pool (`market_app_id= 465814065`) in my attempt and I am about 0.05% away from the correct answer as given on the Algofi front-end interface.

I think the problem I have is that I am calculating the borrow utilization rate (`Borrow Utilization = Amount Lent / Amount Borrowed`) using the wrong functions. This is my attempt:

```
borrowed = asset.get_decimal_amount(market.get_underlying_borrowed())
supplied = asset.get_decimal_amount(market.get_underlying_supplied())
borrow_utilisation = borrowed/supplied
borrow_interest_rate = market.get_total_borrow_interest_rate()/1000000000 
reserve_factor = market.reserve_factor/1000

lend_interest_rate = borrow_utilisation*borrow_interest_rate*(1-reserve_factor)

print(f"lending rate: {lend_interest_rate}")
```

Currently, I am printing: 0.01005185916438448 (1.01%) and [the front-end](https://info.algofi.org/lend-info/) is telling me 1.06%

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The above code gives the correct answer. The Dev team confirmed to me that the UI had a bug.